# Upload data to server from background through FirebaseMessegingService class

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, service, firebase-cloud-messaging

In my app I am using FCM to get notifications. And everything is working when my app is running in foreground but **problem starts when app goes in background or if app gets killed from background, in this case I am getting the notification but data is not uploading on the server.**

For uploading data to the server I am using a separate class where all the required code is written and I am Just calling it in the **FirebaseMessagingService()**  class.

I tried all possible ways, I tried to make separate service but it didn't work.

But I want to upload data to server When I am getting notification.

here is my FirebaseMessegingService Class

```
class FirebaseShareDevMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

private var resultIntent: Intent? = null

override fun onNewToken(p0: String) {
    super.onNewToken(p0)
}

var mNotificationManager: NotificationManager? = null


@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage)

    Log.d("remoteMessage", "onMessageReceived: ${remoteMessage.data}")
    // playing audio and vibration when user se request
    val notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
    val r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, notification)
    r.play()
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        r.isLooping = false
    }

    val data: MutableMap<String, String> = remoteMessage.data
    val deviceId = data["username"]
    val deviceName = data["address"]
    val notificationType = data["notificationType"]


     //codes  
     ....
     ....



    val pendingIntent =
        PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
    builder.setContentTitle(remoteMessage.notification!!.title)
    builder.setContentText(remoteMessage.notification!!.body)
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    builder.setVibrate(longArrayOf(100, 300, 300, 300))
    builder.setStyle(
        NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(
            remoteMessage.notification!!.body
        )
    )

    builder.setAutoCancel(true)
    mNotificationManager =
        applicationContext.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val channelId = "Your_channel_id"
        val channel = NotificationChannel(
            channelId,
            "Channel human readable title",
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        )
        mNotificationManager!!.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        builder.setChannelId(channelId)
    }


    mNotificationManager!!.notify(System.currentTimeMillis().toInt(), builder.build())

    val cal = TimeStampConverter.getTimeStamp(remoteMessage.sentTime.toString())

    Log.d("OnReceivedNotification", "onMessageReceived:$remoteMessage ")


   // here i am calling helper class to upload data to 
   // server.....
    BackendServerHelperClass(applicationContext).saveNotification(
        System.currentTimeMillis().toInt(),
        remoteMessage.notification!!.title!!,
        remoteMessage.notification!!.body!!,
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid.toString(),
        cal.time.toString(),
        deviceId,
        deviceName,
        isAllowedSubLetting.toBoolean(),
        notificationType!!.toInt()           )

 }
}
```

Please help, if there is any way to achieve this.

**Updated**

I tried to give permission of Screen overlay but still its not working

Help will be appreciated:)
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research i found solution.

If we want to receive notification in background and want to do some other stuffs in background if notification is received so we should simply sent the  **"data"** section instead **"notification"** section.

if we sent both **"data"** and **"notification"** then we will receive a notification in background but if you are doing some other stuffs in **"onMessageReceive"** like saving data to **ROOM DATABASE** or uploading some data to **SERVER**. ,  then you should sent only **"data"** section.

**example of data section:**

```
{
"message":{
"token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
"data":{
  "Nick" : "Mario",
  "body" : "great match!",
  "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
  }
 }
}
```

This solved my problem.

You can read more about this on official FCM documentation.

Thanks!! Happy coding:)